# Using a new passport

Tags: visas, passport-renewals, ukraine, biometric-passports

OK you travel to say Ukraine on a bio-metric passport that will shortly expire and then you leave that country after 90 days maximum stay. You go home renew your bio-metric passport and return to Ukraine will the passport control officer be able to see your previous travel dates to that country or will it bring up blank data.

Comment: What scenario do you have in mind? That concern might be somewhat misguided. Reading the biometric info off the chip requires reading the name and date of birth from the machine-readable strip. That information is definitely recorded by many countries and can be used quite effectively to match you and existing records of previous visits, even on another passport and possibly more effectively than the biometrics themselves.